# Rails form not saving, param is missing or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms, erb

I'm working on an issue tracker in Rails. I'm trying to save an issue in a form. The relationship is a Project has many Issues. I'm getting the following error in the browser:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in IssuesController#create`

`param is missing or the value is empty: issue`

And in the server on the terminal:

`Started POST "/issues/new" for ::1 at 2021-07-30 09:42:20 -0400 Processing by IssuesController#create as HTML Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "title"=>"Proj3", "summary"=>"Test3", "description"=>"Test3", "status"=>"complete", "commit"=>"Save "} Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (Allocations: 833)`

Here's the form:

```
                 <%= form_with model: @issue, :url => new_issue_path do |form| %>
                    <p><%= form.label :New_Issue %></p>
                    <h5>Project Title: </h5>
                    <% titles = [] %>
                    <% Project.all.each do |project| %>
                        <% titles << project.title%>
                    <% end %>
                    <p><%= form.select :title, titles %></p>  

                    <h5>Summary: </h5>
                    <p><%= form.text_area :summary, size: "15x3" %></p>
                    <h5>Description: </h5>
                    <p><%= form.text_area :description, size: "30x5" %></p>
                    <h5>Status: </h5>
                    <p><%= form.text_area :status, size: "10x2" %></p>
                    <%= form.submit %>
                <% end %>
```

Here's part of the controller:

```
def issue_params
    params.require(:issue).permit(:summary, :description, :status)
  end

  def create
    # create issues and attach them to the project found by title
    Project.find_by_title(params[:title]).issues.create!(
                                          summary: params[:summary], 
                                          description: params[:description], 
                                          status: params[:status])
    redirect_to issues_url
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The url is wrong in the form_with helper. It should be posting to the create method, not the new method in the controller. Instead of new_issue_path, it should be issues_path. In addition to @Joel Blum's comment below about strong parameters. I don't understand why new_issues_path is being processed by IssueController#create, prob there is an error in the routes. Also the params being received should have the format {issue: {summary: "text", status: "text" etc.}}.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using Strong Parameters in your controller

```
 Project.find_by_title(params[:title]).issues.create!(issue_params)
```

Comment: I think the `title` params should also be included at the `issue_params` since it is also inside the form

Comment: Thanks, Joel Blum, that may have been an issue, but it was not *the* issue. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your strong params are breaking because `@issue` is potentially nil.

In your form, replace `<%= form_with model: @issue, :url => new_issue_path do |form| %>` with `<%= form_with scope: :issue, :url => new_issue_path do |form| %>`